# Is it possible to disable old style numbers for specific cases?

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

Is there a way to disable old style numbering only for specific cases? Right now I have old style numbering enabled globally for my whole document via `\usepackage[osf]{libertine}`, but I want to disable it only for one block of text.

I am hoping there is a way to simply disable old style for that block of text (which has numbers scattered throughout it) rather than having to add `\somecommand{123}` for each number instance in the block of text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Educated guess: enclose the text block in a group and switch to the `fxl` font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\begin{document}

\Large

Some text 0123 with some \emph{456 numbers \textbf{789}} in between.

\begingroup
\usefont{T1}{fxl}{m}{n}\selectfont

Some text 0123 with some \emph{456 numbers \textbf{789}} in between.

\endgroup

Some text 0123 with some \emph{456 numbers \textbf{789}} in between.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works; I'd probably just define a command `\newcommand{\uprightnums}[1]{{\fontfamily{fxl}\selectfont #1}}` and then use `\uprightnums{123}`.

Comment: This probably needs an update due to the new `libertine` version.