# lining figures in tables and math, old style figures in text

Tags: tables, fonts, math-mode, libertine, oldstylenums

I’m using TeXLive 2012, up to date on Ubuntu 12.10. When I use the `libertine` package with the option `osf` and `newtxmath` for math fonts, I get oldstyle numbers everywhere, but I only want to use them in the body, not in tables or math mode. Here’s picture of the problem and an MWE [image: sample image]:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
Old style numbers belong in text 0123456789.
Not in equations:
\begin{equation}
     \cee{C6H12O6 + 6O2 -> 6CO2 ^ + 6H2O ^ + \text{heat} ^}
\end{equation}
Nor in tables:
\begin{table}[!htb]
     \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth} {LCCCCR}
      \toprule
      climate &
      species &
      mean &
      median &
      standard deviation &
      number of experiments \\
      \midrule
      1 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 20,3699   & 20,0335   & 4,453 & 30 \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabulary}
      \caption{mean, median and standard deviation}
      \label{tab:mean}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For `mhchem`'s formulas: `\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\libertineLF}`

Comment: That works only if I use LuaLaTex, not with pdfTeX

Comment: related?: disabling Libertine old style figures in specific places, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `libertine` package per default has the options `lining` and `tabular` activated. In normal text you usually want `proportional` and `oldstyle`, though.

```
\usepackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
```

You don't want to set them as package options, though, but only *after* `newtxmath` has been loaded to get lining figures in math. This could be done by defining `\libertine@figurealign` to an empty definition (with pdfLaTeX) or to `Proportional` (with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) and call `\libertineOsF` afterwards:

```
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}
\makeatother
```

If you now want that `mhchem` has lining numbers in text mode, too, you have to set its font option:

```
\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\libertineLF}
```

In a table you usually want `libertine`'s defaults back. That could be done by redefining `\libertine@figurealign` to `T` (it's definition is empty for proportional figures) when compiling with pdfLaTeX or to `Monospaced` (vs. `Proportional`) with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, and calling the switch `\libertineLF` afterwards. For convenience one could define a command `\libertineTabular`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\libertineTabular{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineLF}
\makeatother
```

This newly defined command should be only used inside the `{table}` environment or, to be more precise, *locally* if you don't want to switch to `tabular` figures for the whole document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\libertineLF}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}
\newcommand\libertineTabular{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineLF}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Old style numbers belong in text 0123456789. \ce{C6H12O6 + 6O2 -> 6CO2 ^ + 6H2O ^ + \text{heat} ^}
Not in equations:
\begin{equation}
  \ce{C6H12O6 + 6O2 -> 6CO2 ^ + 6H2O ^ + \text{heat} ^}
\end{equation}
Nor in tables.

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \caption{mean, median and standard deviation}
  \label{tab:mean}\libertineTabular
  \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth} {LCCCCR}
    \toprule
      climate & species & mean &  median & standard deviation & number of experiments \\
    \midrule
      1 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 20,3699   & 20,0335   & 4,453 & 30 \\
      2 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 23,9864   & 12,6398   & 7,236 & 98 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \qquad 1234567890 \]
Old style numbers belong in text 0123456789.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works as expected, but with pdftex mhchem doesn’t respect the `\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\libertineLF}` command. I found another way from the newtx doc and will edit it in your answer if that’s ok.

Comment: I produced the picture with pdfLaTeX. If it doesn't work for you there must be something else going on...

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the recent changes in the libertine packages. As far as I know some features don’t work with the non-LuaTeX/XeTEX version. I’m still on TeXLive 2012 which was frozen few weeks ago, maybe there were changes in `libertine`.

Comment: Never mind, one should always clean up the project files left in the directory. Your solution works perfectly with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: This is very elaborate, but I still can't see the difference, with any engine, from just loading `libertine` with no options and then a simple `\AtBeginDocument{\libertineOsF}`.  Am I missing something?  (Note, I don't normally deal with math or chemistry, so I'm not trying to be difficult!) This will look bad here, but a simple test: `\newif\ifmytest\mytesttrue\ifmytest\AtBeginDocument{\libertineOsF}\let\libertineTabular\relax\else\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}\newcommand\libertineTabular{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineLF}\makeatother\fi`

Comment: @jon I can't test now but I really would be surprised if you'd get lining tabular figures with only `\AtBeginDocument{\libertineOsF}`

Comment: @jon the tricky part which isn't solved with your simple solution I just checked) is to get proportional figures in the text but monospaced figures in the table.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't thinking about proportional figures....  But couldn't we use `etoolbox` to hook into the `table` environment (`\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\libertineTabular}`) to make it easier to keep all table environments consistent?

Comment: @jon yes I thought about that, too, and if _all_ tables should have them I'd say this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `\usepackage{libertine}`, and immediately after `\begin{document}`, use `\libertineOsF`.
2. Immediately after `\begin{table}[..]`,  use `\libertineLF`.

Comment: Better: `\usepackage{libertine}` and `\AtBeginDocument{\libertineOsF}`.  You don't need to do all the switching back and forth.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @cgnieder the default appearance of numbers for the main text should be set to `proportional` and `osf` (old style figures). The chemistry equations should get proportional lining figures. Finally, tables should contain tabular figures (equal width), but personally I think old style figures are fine in a table.

In the following code I define three font switching commands that can be used to set the desired style on certain places. Then I set the styles as described in the previous paragraph. The main difference to cgnieder's answer is that I set tabular figures for all `tabulary` tables, without the need to specify that on each table by hand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{textcomp}
% \usepackage{libertine}               %% to have tabular (lining) figures in chemistry equations
\usepackage[proportional]{libertine} %% to have proportional (lining) figures in chemistry equations
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\libertineTLF{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineLF}
% \newcommand\libertinePLF{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineLF}    %% not needed
\newcommand\libertineTOsF{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineOsF}
\newcommand\libertinePOsF{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}
\makeatother

%% to have proportional old style figures in the main text
\AtBeginDocument{\libertinePOsF}

%% to have lining figures in chemistry equations;
%% to switch between tabular and  proportional lining figures, use the `proportional` package option of libertine
\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\libertineTLF}

%% to have tabular figures in all tabulary environments
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\TY@tabular}{\libertineTOsF}{}{}  %% tabular old style figures
% \pretocmd{\TY@tabular}{\libertineTLF}{}{}   %% tabular lining figures
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Old style proportional width numbers belong in text 0123456789.
Not in equations (does not make sense chemically):
\begin{align}
     \cee{C6H12O6 + 6666O2 & -> 6666CO2 ^ + 6666H2O ^ + \text{heat} ^} \\
     \cee{C6H12O6 + 1111O2 & -> 1111CO2 ^ + 1111H2O ^ + \text{heat} ^}
\end{align}
Nor in tables:
\begin{table}[!htb]
     \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth} {LCCCCR}
      \toprule
      climate &
      species &
      mean &
      median &
      standard deviation &
      number of experiments \\
      \midrule
      1 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 20,3699   & 20,0335   & 4,453 & 30 \\
      1 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 20,3699   & 11,1111   & 4,453 & 30 \\
      9 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 20,3699   & 99,9999   & 4,453 & 30 \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabulary}
      \caption{mean, median and standard deviation}
      \label{tab:mean}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: Considering that the numbers in the table are probably scientific data I'd think it's rather unusual to use oldstyle figures for them... one could of course use `siunitx` for those and set `siunitx` to use lining figures which could make a specific table setup for the figures redundant...

Comment: @cgnieder I know. I read your objection before, that is why I put a way to change to lining figures in the code. However, I've never seen a convincing explanation why tables should contain lining figures. I think OsF's are easier to read.

Comment: Maybe that's it: I for my part find oldstyle figures quite distracting when comparing data. Maybe that's just because I'm used to lining figures there. I'm curious what Tufte has to say to this matter.

Comment: As far as I remember, Tschichold recommends using old style figures throughout the text, thus in footnotes and tables. But the table in my MWE is rather short, the original extends over the whole page and I think it looks quite bumpy and uneven. Lining figures look much cleaner.

Comment: @TobiasSchula Maybe it is just a matter of taste. But I prepared the code for lining figures, too, just uncomment the other `\pretocmd{...}` line, and comment the one currently active.

Comment: @clemens FWIW, Bringhurst uses proportional old style numbers in [his tables](https://imgur.com/jI4BN3S).

Comment: Someone who does not use _tabulary_ so that he cannot use `\pretocmd{\TY@tabular}` can use e.g. `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\libertineTLF}` instead.