Typesetting the Year in an Old Style
I have recently encountered some unusual ways of displaying years; consider, for instance,

and

QUESTION: Might there be some way(s) in LaTeX which facilitate the typesetting of the displayed formats, and perhaps, other old styles as well?
Thank you.

This is more or less a question of the used font. Some fonts do support minor digits, some not. Especially with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX this is usually not a problem. With PDFLaTeX you can use \oldstylenums{1882}.

See also this question tag, this wiki page, and this database of LaTeX fonts, where each page will usually indicate if osf are available.

Re: other "old style" features, some fonts also support various historical ligatures which may be of interest

LaTeX provides the command \oldstylenums{…}:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
1882 vs. \oldstylenums{1882}

1878 vs. \oldstylenums{1878}
\end{document}


Some font packages also provide an option to use the old style figures for all numbers. And when using the UTF8 engines XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can also use a font, that provide several figures, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128777/277964, How to use Old Style Numbers in XeLaTeX, lining figures in tables and math, old style figures in text and several more questions about oldstylenums.

Thank you for this answer; so the same command \oldstylenums renders a particular style which is dependent on the actual number (year) it is acting upon?

@DDS no, the command renders all number characters in old style, it does not check which number it is.

@DDS How should TeX know, whether a number is a year or not? Is 1 a year? Is 1000 a year? Is 100000 a year? All of them can be years, but all of them also can be the number of chicken living on a farm.

@DDS all the oldstylenums digits or figures are the same. If you see the 8 is always that way, the 1 is always that way and that...

The is not seven in 1882. See al the 8, they all look the same
