# Monospaced lining figures in tables, proportional lining or oldstyle figures in math, tikz pictures, or normal text

Tags: tables, libertine, scrbook, oldstylenums

I am trying to set a text where `monospaced` `lining` figures are used within tables (`tabulars`, `longtable` etc.), `proportional` `lining` figures in `tikz` pictures and `math` environments, as well as `proportional` `oldstyle` figures throughout the normal text.

Something similar has been asked before in the [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114331/lining-figures-in-tables-and-math-old-style-figures-in-text).

However, I am not quite happy with the answers since they do not work flawless for me. That is why I would like to ask this question again relating to the specific issues I observe.

At the moment I use the following code in my header:

```
    \usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
      \makeatletter
        \AtBeginDocument{\libertineOsF}
      \makeatother
```

This more or less accomplishes the task. However, please note the `11` at the end of the sentence. There is too much kerning between both single numbers. It might not look a lot, however, I find it rather annoying.

**Example a (Correct table, annoying inline figures):**
[image]

Here is another example where the `11` looks right but I do not have `monospaced` figures in the table (i.e., the figures do not align in the table anymore):

**Example b (Incorrect table, inline figures are ok):**
[image]

I tried all the solutions proposed in the thread above. However, nothing really helped.

**Update:**

The solution should make sure that the `table of content` is unaffected by the changes. The current solution proposed by Piet van Oostrum changes both the chapter/section numbers as well as the page numbers (originally the chapter/section numbers were `monospaced` `oldstyle` figures whereby the page numbers where `monospaced` `lining` figures).

---

Here are the MWEs:

**Example a:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
           11pt]{scrbook} 

           \usepackage{libertine}
           \usepackage{siunitx}
           \sisetup{
              group-digits=true,        
              group-minimum-digits=4,  
              add-integer-zero=false,
              detect-all = true,
              mode=math
        }

        \usepackage[british]{babel} 
        \usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
          \makeatletter
            \AtBeginDocument{\libertineOsF}
          \makeatother 


\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=0.2]}
 \hline
 {Big number} & {Small number} \\ \hline
 1711 & .22 \\
 3333 & .11 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{center}

This is just some meaningless text where I want to show you, what is going on (see Figure~3; $p < .33$). Really, this text does not mean anything. Nevertheless, it is useful and contains probably more than 55 letters. Here you see the annoying fact with some of the figures: 11.

\end{document}
```

**Example b:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
           11pt]{scrbook} 

           \usepackage{libertine}
           \usepackage{siunitx}
           \sisetup{
              group-digits=true,        
              group-minimum-digits=4,  
              add-integer-zero=false,
              detect-all = true,
              mode=math
        }

        \usepackage[british]{babel} 

        \usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
          \makeatletter
            \AtBeginDocument{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}
          \makeatother 


\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=0.2]}
 \hline
 {Big number} & {Small number} \\ \hline
 1711 & .22 \\
 3333 & .11 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{center}

This is just some meaningless text where I want to show you, what is going on (see Figure 3; $p < .33$). Really, this text does not mean anything. Nevertheless, it is useful and contains probably more than 55 letters. Here you see the annoying fact with some of the figures: 11.


\end{document}
```

---

This might also be a good question for [meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/): How to ask a question that has already been asked but is not fully answered although it is marked as "answered"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that you refer to has the following:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}
\newcommand\libertineTabular{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineLF}
\makeatother
```

and then it uses `\libertineTabular` before the `tabular` environment. That will also work in your case.

```
\begin{center}\libertineTabular
 \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=0.2]}
```

You can also make it automatic with the use of the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-digits=true,        
  group-minimum-digits=4,  
  add-integer-zero=false,
  detect-all = true,
  mode=math
}

\usepackage[british]{babel} 
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces, libertine]{newtxmath}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\def\libertine@figurealign{}\libertineOsF}
\newcommand\libertineTabular{\def\libertine@figurealign{T}\libertineLF}
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\libertineTabular}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=0.2]}
 \hline
 {Big number} & {Small number} \\ \hline
 1711 & .22 \\
 3333 & .11 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{center}

This is just some meaningless text where I want to show you, what is going on (see Figure~3; $p < .33$). Really, this text does not mean anything. Nevertheless, it is useful and contains probably more than 55 letters. Here you see the annoying fact with some of the figures: 11.

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I just realised that now the page numbers in the table of contents (+ table of figures etc. are not monospaced anymore). Is there an easy way to change this?

Comment: I think `{\libertineTabular\tableofcontents}` and similar for the others, will be the simplest, but then all figures in these tables will be monospaced, not just the page numbers.